# Commutator in product vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

Consider a vector space $V=V_1\otimes V_2\otimes V_3$ constructed as the tensor product of finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces $V_1, V_2, V_3$. For linear operators on $V$, we use subindices to indicate which tensor factor spaces they act nontrivially, for example, $F_{12}$ acts non-trivially on $V_1,V_2$ and trivially on $V_3$, i.e. $F_{12}$ is of the form $\sum_{i,j}f_i\otimes g_j \otimes I$, where $I$ is the identity operator.

**Statement**: If $[F_{12},G_{13}]=H_{23}$, then $H_{23}=0$.

This is easily proved by taking partial trace on $V_1$ on both sides. **Question: is the following "multiplicative version" of this statement still true?**

**Statement($\times$)**: If  $F_{12}G_{13}F^{-1}_{12}G^{-1}_{13}=H_{23}$, then $H_{23}=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Statement(×) is false. Here is a counterexample:

Let
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{12}&=&(I+\sigma_1^x)\sigma_2^z/2+(I-\sigma_1^x)/2, \\G_{13}&=&(I+\sigma_1^z)\sigma_3^x/2+(I-\sigma_1^z)/2, 
\end{eqnarray}
where $\sigma^{x,y,z}$ are [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). (In quantum computing context, $F_{12}$ and $G_{13}$ are rotated versions of the [controlled NOT gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate)). Then by a direct calculation, we have
$$H_{23}=F_{12}G_{13}F^{-1}_{12}G^{-1}_{13}=(I-\sigma_2^z)\sigma_3^x/2+(I+\sigma_2^z)/2\neq \lambda I.$$